# what is the equivalent control we can use in Vb6 to get the window handle that the control is bound to

Tags: vb6

in c# we can use `IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle` to get the window handle that the control is bound to.
which control we can use in vb6 to gets the window handle that the control is bound to?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the hWnd property of the Form object to get the window handle of the form or control.

```
Dim hWnd As Long
hWnd = Form1.hWnd
```

You can also use the hWnd property of other controls, such as buttons, labels, and text boxes, to get their window handles.